# How to hide an img tag when it opens on mobile?

Tags: image

Can you please tell me how to hide an img tag when it opens on mobile? Please suggest me if there is any css solution or simple javascript.

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no css designed to aim all mobiles phones. However, there is screen selectors named `@media`. Please take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp for information.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var isMobile = /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
  if (isMobile)
    $('#imgID').hide();
  });
```